# Can not send credentials through CORS on IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, tomcat, cors, httpclient, credentials

I have a poltergeist problem and I come to you after a long time going around with this problem.

I have an Hybrid App with this specs:

```
-Ionic 3.9.2
-Angular 5.2.11
-Cordova Android 8.1.0 and iOS 5.1.1
-Cordova 8.0.0
```

My app make request to a SOAP backend which is secured with a secured cookie JSESSIONID (Tomcat server).

I had to enable CORS so that my requests are able to reach the backend, this is the Tomcat CORS filter:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>ionic://localhost,http://localhost</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,SOAPAction,Cache-Control</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I do login against the backend the server SETS a cookie (JSESSION) which is used to send in subsequent request to backend to authenticate in secured WS.
This is the code to make request with `httpclient angular`(Same for subsequent request)

```
 this.http.post(wsurl, xml, {
        withCredentials: true,
        responseType: 'text',
        headers: headers,
        observe: 'response'
      })
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {})
        .catch(err =>{})
```

My problem is that the backend, after enable CORS, not authenticate my subsequent request on iOS/safari **(Android, chrome works fine)**

But this is the poltergeist:

**Same build** of app deployed on Iphone 6 iOS v12.4.5 **works fine.** On a iPhone X with iOS v 14 and simulators(any version) not work.

Backend returns this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
            <faultstring>User has not a valid M4Session</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:exceptionName xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">com.meta4.soapservices.exception.M4SoapException</ns1:exceptionName>
                <ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">cd102015</ns2:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem with iOS14, works with iOS13. Seems like they changed something here. I hope someone has info about this.

Comment: To me is very strange. Same build not works on a ios 14 and ios 13.7 but it works on a ios 12.5..

Comment: I have a similar issue with Cordova, Signalr, CORS and iOS 14, but only in release mode. It works on iOS 13... could you figure anything out? Actually building our cordova app works, but not when this is integrated in a Webview within a native App